# How to pass variables to a pipeline job without using jenkins cli?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Currently i have configured two jobs, one for to pass parameters and the other for pipeline using pipeline script

1.) parameter job

```
cat "artifactlist.csv" | while IFS='' read -r line; do
Artifact_id="$(echo "$line")"
echo "$Artifact_id"
java -jar /home/nxa35638/jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL build test_pipeline
```

2.) test_pipeline

```
stage 'Test_data_cleanup'
node(Slave01) {
build job: 'jobs/Delete_data', parameters: [string(name: 'Artifact_id', value: "${Artifact_id}")]
stage 'Test_data_cleanup'
node(Slave01) {
build job: 'jobs/create_data', parameters: [string(name: 'Artifact_id', value: "${Artifact_id}")]
}
```

Instead of using a separate job to pass the parameters, is there any option that we use only pipeline job and simply build it for all parameters ?

i didn't find any concrete solution for the same, please provide your valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can use readFile pipeline step https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace and Groovy features to make something like:

```
node(Slave01) {
    def artifacts = readFile "artifactlist.csv" 
    artifacts.split("\n").each { artifactId ->
        build job: 'jobs/Delete_data', parameters: [string(name: 'Artifact_id', value: "${artifactId}")]
    } 
}
```